# What is the difference between rite and ritual?

Tags: differences

I have found the word rite or ritual used separately and have also found written together like "rite and ritual". But, what are differences between them. If they are related to religions, Give me examples of both rite and ritual from Hindu and christian or buddhist relegion.

Comment: First you should show your own work.  For example, from a dictionary.

Comment: It would be better to be understood from my question itself where i have stated about rite and ritual written together and wrtten together, we can find these words if googled, Let alone showing dictionery

Comment: It would actually be better if you read and complied with the rules of this site!  One reason for closing a question reads: "Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic."  That is why GEdgar posted his comment.

Answer (score 7):

*Oxford Dictionaries On-line* defines ***rite*** as *a religious or other solemn ceremony or act*.

***Ritual*** is defined as *a religious or solemn ceremony consisting of a series of actions performed according to a prescribed order: e.g. ancient fertility rituals*

Both words are clearly closely connected. However *rite* is used more as a headline term that refers to a particular ceremony, the detailed enactment of which constitutes a *ritual*.

For example one could say that baptism was a Christian *rite*. But if one was describing the detailed manner in which it takes place, which varies greatly by denomination, one would be describing a number of different *rituals*

Both terms are used extensively in a metaphorical or figurative sense. e.g. *The ritual of Sunday lunch in the Johnson household is unfailingly consistent*.

Answer (score 2):

Not much difference. Both *rite* and ritual can be count nouns, referring to individual formal events.

- *The prescribed rite/ritual for the blessing of a public house by a subdeacon takes an hour*.

However, *ritual* (and not *rite*) also has an abstract non-count sense as well,
referring to the state of having formal rites in the first place.

- *There is enormous symbolism in ritual, especially religious ritual.*